# How to sort in descending order with ramda's sortBy function?

Tags: javascript, sorting, ramda.js

When using ramda's **sort** function I can use the **descend** function to create a descending comparator:

```js
console.log(R.sort(R.descend(R.prop(0)))([[2],[3],[1]]))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

With **sortBy** this does not work. The list is sorted in ascending order by default.

`R.sortBy(R.prop(0))([[2],[3],[1]])`

The only solution I can think of is to explicitly reverse the list after sorting, but isn't there a more elegant way to achieve that?

Comment: A more elegant way to achieve *what*?  You already showed that you have a reasonable way to create a descending sorter: `sort(descend(prop(0))`.  Are you suggesting that this should be achievable with `sortBy` as well as with `sort`?  What do you see missing?

Comment: I just thought there would be a way to also use the descend function here. After looking up the implementation of sortBy it makes sense why it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ramda has several different sorting capabilities.

Most familiar is `sort`, which is essentially a non-mutating pure function version of the `Array.prototype.sort` method.  You pass it a comparator: a binary function which must return a number.  If the number is negative, the first argument comes ahead of the second one in the result; if it's positive, the second argument comes ahead of the first one; it it's zero, you express no preference, although most implementations these days are stable, which means that the first argument would come ahead.

`sortWith` is a way to string together several such comparators.  If you wanted to sort by last name, and -- if those are the same -- by first name, you could pass a last-name comparator and a first-name one and it will sort as you desired.

To help create such comparator functions, Ramda also offers `ascend` and `descend`, which accept a function which returns an ordered type such as the built-in String, Number, and Date types, or anything with an appropriate `valueOf` method, and returns a comparator that can be passed to `sort`.  Thus if the objects you want to sort each has a numeric `age` property, you can sort them by decreasing age by passing `descend(o => o.age)` (equivalently, `descend(prop('age'))`) to `R.sort` or `Array.prototype.sort` or -- as one of an array of comparators -- to `R.sortWith`.

But often enough, we would like something simpler.  *I just want to sort these by their type code*.  For the simplest cases, Ramda offers `sortBy`, which does not take a comparator but simply a function which returns something of an ordered type.  Most commonly this is used by simply extracting a property from your object: `sortBy(prop('type'))`, but you can do whatever transformation you like.

But there is no equivalent to `ascend`/`descend` for `sortBy`.  While of course something like that could be written, it's already covered by `sort(a/descend(myFunc))`.

Comment: why not using `reverse()` after the sortBy?

Comment: @YannickSchuchmann: you certainly could.  There are often multiple ways to accomplish such things.

Comment: if you reverse though aren't you duplicating the operations?

Comment: @DanielThompson: Well, you're adding an `O(n)` operation to an `O(n * log(n))` operation one, which means, while yes, you are adding cycles, you're not increasing the algorithmic complexity.  If it makes the code simpler, it might be worth the small increase in runtime.  Of course, `descend` covers that case.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

For `sortBy` you need to invert the resulting value in order to affect the sort direction. This can be done with a small `desc` function:

```
const desc = a => -a;
const customSort = R.sortBy(R.compose(desc, R.prop(0)));

customSort([[1], [3], [2], [4]]);

// Result: [[4], [3], [2], [1]]
```

Working example: https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.26.1#?const%20desc%20%3D%20a%20%3D%3E%20-a%3B%0Aconst%20customSort%20%3D%20R.sortBy%28R.compose%28desc%2C%20R.prop%280%29%29%29%3B%0A%0AcustomSort%28%5B%5B1%5D%2C%20%5B3%5D%2C%20%5B2%5D%2C%20%5B4%5D%5D%29%3B

**Previous answer using `sortWith`:**

`sortWith` will get you the result you want.

```
const customSort = R.sortWith([R.descend(R.prop(0))]);

customSort([[1], [3], [2], [4]]);

// Result: [[4], [3], [2], [1]]
```

Working example: https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.26.1#?const%20customSort%20%3D%20R.sortWith%28%5BR.descend%28R.prop%280%29%29%5D%29%3B%0A%0AcustomSort%28%5B%5B1%5D%2C%20%5B3%5D%2C%20%5B2%5D%2C%20%5B4%5D%5D%29%3B

Comment: How is it better than `sortBy`?

Comment: Thanks. I guess `R.sortBy(R.compose(R.negate, R.prop(0)));` works as well.

Comment: But note that `sortBy` works with any ordered type, not just Numbers.  You can't negate a String.  (I haven't tried with Dates or objects that have a proper `valueOf`; the coercion from multiplication might just make that work; but I wouldn't like to count on it.)